# Does the Visionary's Mass Levitation power apply to Scum and Villany?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

In the Sentinels of the Multiverse card game, the Visionary has an ongoing card Mass Levitation with the power:

> Until the start of your next turn, reduce damage dealt by environment cards by 3.

The Scum and Villany environment card from the Rook City expansion states:

> At the start of the environment turn, the villain character card deals each hero target **H** minus 1 melee damage and destroys this card.

So, if I had four heroes, Scum and Villany would result in all of my heroes taking three melee damage.  Can Mass Levitation's power prevent this damage?

My assumption is that even though the environment card *triggers* the villain card dealing damage to the heroes, the *villain card* is the actual source of damage for calculating effects, damage reduction, nemesis damage, etc.  Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Mass Levitation does not apply in this case, for exactly the reason you expect.**

The key word here is "deals": Mass Levitation prevents damage *dealt* by the environment. The environment card doesn't deal damage though - it actually causes the *villain* to deal damage - so Mass Levitation has no effect here.